# How to set the height/width of a view (f.e. Label) to the size of its content?

Tags: android, layout, xamarin.forms, view

I want to set the height of a `View` in `Xamarin.Forms`exactly to the size of its content. For example I want a `Label` only to be as high as its text.

In **Android** I can do something like `layout_height="wrap_content"`. Is there something similar in `Xamarin.Forms`? Can I use `HeightRequest` for this and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question when you mention **View**, instead of something specific like **Label**, so there are some things to consider in different **View** scenarios:-

You can use **HorizontalOptions** and **VerticalOptions** properties of a **View** object to help with this, i.e. **LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand** or **LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand** etc.

Yes - you can specify **HeightRequest** and **WidthRequest** on a **View** to indicate your preference to an area *width* and *height* to be reserved for the *view* through *layout*, although this is not guaranteed, dependent on other layout controls / views used.

If we are talking specifically to the **Label** control, this will not expand the text size, of a specific **Label** font size used, to fit the parent **View** that you specify though.  To accomplish this you would have to set the **Scale** property as appropriate to scale the **Label** to the container it is used in.

**Update 1:-**

Using the following example code, the height is already altered automatically to fit the Label height text that is displayed?

```
        StackLayout  cobjStackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
        };

        Label objLabel1 = new Label();
        objLabel1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        objLabel1.Text = "This is a label";
        cobjStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel1);

        Label objLabel2 = new Label();
        objLabel2.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        objLabel2.Text = "This is another label with different font size";
        objLabel2.Font = Font.OfSize("Arial", 48);
        cobjStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel2);


        this.Content = cobjStackLayout;
```

**Update 2:-**
Yes - there is an unexpected filling vertically to the end of the **ContentPage**, that is occurring when you are using just **one** **Label**.

If you try the following you should experience, around just the text, what you are after, using just **1 Label**:-

```
        cobjStackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
        };

        Label objLabel1 = new Label();
        objLabel1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        objLabel1.Text = "This is a label";
        cobjStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel1);

        this.Content = cobjStackLayout;
```

**Update 3:-**

Here is a version that doesn't use the parent to set the HorizontalOptions/VerticalOptions so things might be a little clearer about when I say that LayoutOptions specified on different parts of a hierarchy affect the output:-

```
        cobjStackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        };

        Label objLabel1 = new Label();
        objLabel1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        objLabel1.Text = "This is a label";
        objLabel1.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        objLabel1.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        cobjStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel1);


        this.Content = cobjStackLayout;
```

Remember its not enough sometimes to just set the **HorizontalOptions** or **VerticalOptions** on a **View** that you are interested in controlling to get your desired effect.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. I don't want to expand a child view within its parent. I just want my Label to be exactly as high as its text, not any higher.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some extra info/code based on your comment.

Comment: Try that with just one `Label` and change the orientation of the `StackLayout` to horizontal. You'll see what I mean. The Label fills the whole screen then, but I want it to only wrap the text.

Comment: THAT (update 2) looks much better but still not perfect. Anyway, it bothers me that you can't set this to the `Label` but have "manipulate" the parent view for this. Doesn't feel right.

Comment: Not perfect?, It fits the text?  Alternatively try *Update 3* that shows it doesn't have to be done on the *Parent*.  *HorizontalOptions* and *VerticalOptions* apply to *all* views.  Settings at different parts of an hierarchy affect the rendered output.